# How does the equarion come from 5-110 to 5-112?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It says that the equation is multiplied by 2du_0/dy but I can't see any trace of the 2. I'm aware that it is a simple question but if you can explain it I would be very glad.

[image]

Comment: The idea is that $\displaystyle\frac d{dy}\left(\frac{du_0(y)}{dy}\right)^2=2\frac{du_0(y)}{dy}\frac {d^2 u_0(y)}{(dy)^2}$ (expand too $\displaystyle\frac d{dy}(u_0(y)^2)$ )

Comment: You should check the operation by goind backwards, that is by taking the derivative in (5-112) to recover (5-111) and (5-110).